# Is app.html still used in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2

Does ionic 2 still use the app.html file? The tutorial docs (2nd page) currently says it's located at src/app/app.html
The udemy course hasn't mentioned that file at all. So I was wondering if ionic has been updated and the docs haven't, or I'm just not creating the file with the start command for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Ionic 2's docs, it looks like their initial example for starting a new app does not include any tutorial files. When I used the `ionic start` command with `tutorial` on the end, then I had the app.html file they were referring to.

```sh
ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2
```

Here's mine:
[image]

If you don't include `tutorial` on the end, then you are just getting a barebones project started and so you won't have the tutorial files.

Doc Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro! That makes sense! Although it's really unclear by he docs if that is really the case >< can anyone else confirm it's correct? Also is the file viewable? I served the app but no file was created

Comment: My initial answer was incorrect. I decided to check it out hands on and found that you may not have been using the tutorial they intended. When I ran `ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2`, I had the app.html file you referenced being missing.

Comment: Ah I seeee!! Thanks a bunch dude. I'll follow along with the tutorial template then! :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for misleading you with the first answer.

Comment: No problem man. I'm coming from the first version of ionic too. It's totally different o.O

Comment: Hey Barry! I just realised that recently an app.html file is being created. The component declaration in the app.component.ts file points to the file that has the <ion-nav> tag instead of having it written as a string in the same file. Seems things are still being changed around O.o